# Ajax.BeginForm not firing up Jquery function

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

When I use `Ajax.BeginForm` to display form with `ASP.NET MVC` `Razor`, I'm not able to fire up `jquery` event on the client side.

The problem is that I use `ajax` to display the form.

so I am thinking that the client browser is not detecting that the form is there.

I have tried to use like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("InsertAbending", "Home",
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                OnBegin = "highlighter"
            },new {@id = "create"}))
{
```

and the javascript is:

```
function highlighter() {
            $('form').highlight();
        }
```

This would fire up this simple event that highlights the div around the form. I got the jquery script from this page:

http://www.keyframesandcode.com/resources/javascript/jQuery/demos/highlight-demo.html#form-demo

But it's not working, only when used flat based HTML.

Could someone tell me how to force the ajax form to fire up particual javascript function?

Sincerly
AGH

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have included the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script to your page (**after** your inclusion to jquery.js script) in order for the Ajax.BeginForm to work as an AJAX form.

Comment: Well I added just a simple form on the same page and the ajax form and that simple form is working. So the script references in the <head> tag seems to be correct. But the ajax form on not working, and I think the problem is that the .highlight event is not firing up when the ajax form is displayed.